# Get the Value of the selected radio button from a dynamically created set

Tags: jquery, html

I have a group of dynamically created radio button groups and I wish to get the value of the currently selected Item if the 'Fault' item is selected. I have included just two of the fieldsets (There are 18 in total) I have no control of the id or name of the groups until after they are created. The fieldsets are contained in a table but I have omitted this because of space.  Can anyone see how to get at the values?

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="false"     data-theme="b" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-group-theme-    b ui-corner-all"><div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
                                            <!-- mobileradiobutton_9 -->
<span dsid="mobileradiobutton_9_1"   class="vehicle_check_page_mobileradiobutton_9" name="mobileradiobutton_9"   dsrefid="mobileradiobutton_9" _idx="_1">

<div class="ui-radio"><label id="vehicle_check_page_mobileradiobutton_9_label_1" for="vehicle_check_page_mobileradiobutton_9_1" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-first-child ui-btn-active ui-radio-on" _idx="_1">OK</label><input type="radio" name="mobileradiogroup_8_1" id="vehicle_check_page_mobileradiobutton_9_1" style="display:none" width="70px" tabindex="1" value="1,OK" _idx="_1" data-cacheval="false"></div></span>
 <!-- mobileradiobutton_10 -->
<span dsid="mobileradiobutton_10_1" class="vehicle_check_page_mobileradiobutton_10" name="mobileradiobutton_10" dsrefid="mobileradiobutton_10" _idx="_1">
```

Fault

OK
 
   

 Fault

Comment: I have tried quite a few mostly found here!      //var I =$(this).map(function(index,dom){return dom.id});  
 //var id = $(this)(":selected").attr("id");
//var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');
//var txt=$('input[name=radio_group]:checked').val();
//var txt= $(this.value);

Comment: Start with `$('[type=radio]:checked')`, it returns all selected radio buttons.

Comment: The suggested snippet returns all of the selected item and I am struggling to drill down and get the value.  If I do $("input:radio:checked").each(function() {       
     alert(this.value);
        }) ;  Then this returns all of the values in turn, but I would like to respond immediately.   I suppose I could create a function the used the loop and check the value after each item is clicked and return items where a fault was selected but this would get messy when more than one fault was selected!